# Backbone: reverse collection order with comparator

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm building a Backbone app which displays a list of books, but when I add a new book, through the Edit view, he goes to the bottom of the list instead to the top. So basically I want to reverse the order of my collection with a Comparator but what I tried it's not working:

```
comparator: function (model) {
    return -model.get('id');
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle with all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/swayziak/9R9zU/4/

I don't know if the problem is only related with the comparator or if I need to change something more in other part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Why not a simple `prepend` instead of `append`

```
this.$el.prepend(
```

Comment: Thanks that works well. I was so focused in using the comparator that I didn't thought in another options.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator is looking for the model IDs:

```
comparator: function (model) {
    return -model.get('id');
}
```

but none of your models have `id` attributes. Usually the `id` would come from the server so the server would supply the initial `id` values when bootstrapping the collection and then new `id`s would be assigned (by the server) when you [`save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) the model.

If you add `id`s to your data then things will start to make more sense.

You'll also need to adjust your fiddle to:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
```

instead of:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderBook);
```

since your editing panel will kill off all the HTML and you'll need to re-render the whole collection.

Once you get past that, you'll find that your *Edit* link no longer works. That's because you're trying to re-use views while messing around with the content of their `el`'s. Instead, you should:

1. Stop trying to re-use views, it is almost never worth the hassle.
2. Give each view its own unique `el`.
3. Call `view.remove()` to get rid of a view before putting a new one in the common container.
4. Then create the new view, render it, and put its `el` in the container.

You'll find that since all your views share a common container, you'll no longer need to bind your collection view to the collection's `'add'` event, you'll be tossing and rebuilding the whole view instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the recommendations, I'm going to try what you suggest. Speaking of the comparator, do you think that I need to create an id in each of the models until I have the code connected to the server?

Comment: @user2473588: You might be able to use [Backbone's internal `cid`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) as a temporary measure. Or assign and maintain your own `id`s if that's easier to remember and clean up when you start talking to the server.

Comment: I'm going to check out the cid. Thanks